# probem while working with ITLSSPProc.dll

Tags: java, dll

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unable to open the port by calling Native method from ITLSSPProc.dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14521284/unable-to-open-the-port-by-calling-native-method-from-itlsspproc-dll)

i am working with itlsspproc.dll but gets the following error

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
>   itl.ssp.proc.ITLSSPProcLoader.OpenSSPComPort(Litl/ssp/proc/ITLSSPProcLoader$SSP_COMMAND;)I
>   at itl.ssp.proc.ITLSSPProcLoader.OpenSSPComPort(Native Method)at
>   itl.ssp.proc.ITLSSPProcLoader.main(ITLSSPProcLoader.java:81)

here is my code

package itl.ssp.proc;

```
    public class ITLSSPProcLoader {
        public class SSP_FULL_KEY
        {
            long FixedKey;
            long EncryptKey;
            public SSP_FULL_KEY(long fix, long encr)
            {
                FixedKey = fix;
                EncryptKey = encr;
            }
    }

    public class SSP_COMMAND
        {
            //string PortNumber; 
            SSP_FULL_KEY key;
            int BaudRate; // baud rate of the packet 
            int Timeout; // how long in ms to wait for a reply from the slave 
            String PortNumber; // the serial com port number of the host 
            String SSPAddress; // the SSP address of the slave 
            String RetryLevel; // how many retries to the slave for non-response 
            String EncryptionStatus; // is this an encrypted command 0 - No, 1 - Yes 
            String CommandDataLength; // Number of bytes in the command 
            String[] CommandData = new String[255]; // Array containing the command bytes 
            String ResponseStatus; // Response Status (PORT_STATUS enum) 
            String ResponseDataLength; // how many bytes in the response 
            String ResponseData[] = new String[255]; // an array of response data 
            String IgnoreError; // flag to suppress error box (0 - display,1- suppress) 

            public SSP_COMMAND(String comport)
            {
                BaudRate = 9600;
                Timeout = 500;
                PortNumber =  comport;
                System.out.println("sagar "+PortNumber);
                RetryLevel = "5";
                IgnoreError = "0";
                EncryptionStatus = "0";
                ResponseStatus = "0";
                ResponseDataLength = "0";
                SSPAddress = "0";
                CommandDataLength = "0";
                key = new SSP_FULL_KEY(012345670123, 012345670123);

            }
        } 

        public native static int  OpenSSPComPort (SSP_COMMAND cmd);
        public native static  int  CloseSSPComPort();
        public ITLSSPProcLoader()
        {
            try
            {
                System.loadLibrary("ITLSSPProc");
                System.out.println("library is loaded");

            }catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
        public static void main(String args[])
        {


            ITLSSPProcLoader itl = new ITLSSPProcLoader();

            SSP_COMMAND cmd = itl.new  SSP_COMMAND("com7");

            System.out.println("open port"+OpenSSPComPort(cmd)); //error comes here

            System.out.println("close" +CloseSSPComPort());


        }
    }


 i have incuded the dll in project folder and also paste in system32 folder in window directory. i struct on this error please help if any one works on this
```